# SHOW KEYS in Aerospike?

Tags: aerospike

I'm new to Aerospike and am probably missing something fundamental, but I'm trying to see an enumeration of the `Keys` in a `Set` (I'm purposefully avoiding the word "list" because it's a datatype).

For example,

- To see all the `Namespaces`, the docs say to use `SHOW NAMESPACES`
- To see all the `Sets`, we can use `SHOW SETS`

If I want to see all the unique `Keys` in a `Set` ... what command can I use?

It seems like one can use `client.scan()` ... but that seems like a super heavy way to get *just* the key (since it fetches all the bin data as well).

Any recommendations are appreciated!  As of right now, I'm thinking of inserting (deleting) into (from) a meta-record.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you @pgupta for pointing me in the right direction.

This actually has two parts:

1. In order to retrieve original keys from the server, one must -- during `put()` calls -- set policy to save the key value server-side (otherwise, it seems only a digest/hash is stored?).

Here's an example in Python:

```
aerospike_client.put(key, {'bin': 'value'}, policy={'key': aerospike.POLICY_KEY_SEND})
```

2. Then (modified Aerospike's [own documentation](https://www.aerospike.com/apidocs/python/scan.html#aerospike.Scan.foreach)), you perform a scan and set the policy to not return the bin data.  From this, you can extract the keys:

Example:

```
keys = []
scan = client.scan('namespace', 'set')
scan_opts = { 'concurrent': True, 'nobins': True, 'priority': aerospike.SCAN_PRIORITY_MEDIUM }
for x in (scan.results(policy=scan_opts)): keys.append(x[0][2])
```

The need to iterate over the result still seems a little clunky to me; I still think that using a 'master-key' Record to store a list of all the *other* keys will be more performant, in my case -- in this way, I can simply make one `get()` call to the Aerospike server to retrieve the list.

Comment: In Enterprise Edition, Strong Consistency mode guarantees no committed writes will ever be lost.  In Community Edition, you only have AP mode. In your scheme, every record created becomes a multi-record operation - one to create the record itself, second to update the master record list.  The list by itself will be limited by the max record size. Ensure the method works through rare split-brain situations in AP mode, write errors, timeouts.  By default, client only sends RIPEMD160 hash of (key, key type, setname) as record digest (key) to server. Some users save the key as a bin in the record.

Comment: Also how often do you plan to create new keys? If the rate is high, this record containing all keys will itself become a hot-key.

Answer (score 1):

You can choose not bring the data back by setting includeBinData in ScanPolicy to false.